# Function need a loop solution

Tags: c, function, loops, matrix

I have this function and i wanna do when function "play" is executed one time that the function bot stop any idea but i still need to check all the matrix values because it can be one of all the positions.function play is a void function to.

```
void bot(char board[8][8],char color){
    int i;
    char j;
    for(i=0;i<8;i++){
        for(j=0;j<8;j++){
            if (board[i][j]=='.'){
                if (flanked(board,i,j,color)>0){
                    play(board,i,j,color);
                }
            }        
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the call to `bot` to end after a single call to `play`, just `return` at that time.

```
void bot(char board[8][8],char color){
    int i;
    char j;
    for(i=0;i<8;i++){
        for(j=0;j<8;j++){
            if (board[i][j]=='.'){
                if (flanked(board,i,j,color)>0){
                    play(board,i,j,color);
                    return;
                }
            }        
        }
    }
}
```